# Confirmation box display based on a condition on server side

Tags: prompt, confirmation

I want to display a confirmation dialog in an ASP.Net application. It's a complex form, and the user would get a confirmation prompt when he presses the save button for example.

The problem is, that the dialog would be displayed or, not displayed based on a condition on the server side. What is the best way to implement this.

Comment: If you can't submit the form/page to the server then you will need to make an AJAX call instead.